# Bootgrid generates 0s for every data in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used bootgrid for my website after having issues on rendering table by datatables. Bootgrid render the table well. The table becomes a data grid with it and not like with datatables as i asked from a previous question. But after bootgrid renders the table all the values become 0s. Why is that ? Is there any solution to fix this ?

I just used this piece of code

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#data_table').bootgrid();
    });
```

I'm referencing JQuery with this

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more code with the datasource that you are using or create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: actually i have created the table already when I'm calling the function. Becuase the table created by the page when it is loading with the data provided to it.

Comment: If you see the console here, the error is $ is undefined.

Comment: I mean i'm using codeigniter and in the controller it passes the values for the table and in the view the table will be created when the page is loading. and then the table will redesign by the plugin after this code. As it say in this page http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples   in its basic example

Comment: @ user3263194 I'll check the console. thanks for that. But the jquery is loaded in the head section.

Comment: In the console this is what i got
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: How are you referencing jQuery? any online link?

Comment: i have updated it.how i referenced jquery.

Comment: Check the fiddle. Here it works fine 
http://jsfiddle.net/bne877up/3/

Comment: @user3263194
data-column-id data-type maybe i missed them. that could be the reason. Am I right ?
I think i haven't add those data attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading bootgrid with data provided to it, then you have to add "data-column-id" attribute to the column.

for example: for column Sender, table structure should be like this:

```
<table id="data_table">
<thead><tr>
<th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a littles issue.
It also changes my columns that I had something like this
<a href="#" onclick="confirm_delete(<?php echo $row['product_id']?>)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete" class="pull-right text-danger" style="margin-left: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
which is an a tag. How to fix that and stop changing the data inside <td> ??

Comment: What does it become after changing?

Comment: the code inside that a tag is gone and just the td tag without it.